# How to make request (type : POST) of JSONObject in android using volley library?

Tags: json, sharedpreferences, android-volley, listpreference, jsonobjectrequest

I want to make a JsonObjectRequest using POST method with volley library so that i can save my data on the server.

For the same, i've an API of jsonObject as follows:

```
{"settings":{"notification":30,"time":4}}
```

The java code for the same is as follows ;

```
 public void sendrequest(String urlset)
    {
        RequestQueue requestQueue1=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest1=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlset, json, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
//code for getting some response from the method
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//code in order to check the error 
            }
        });

    }
```

How can this be done so that I am able to post my data on the server using the above code (for reference).

Thanks in advance.

After a few attempts i tried doing this:

```
public void sendrequest(String urlset)
    {
        RequestQueue requestQueue1=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        String a,b;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",MODE_PRIVATE);

        a=sharedPreferences1.getString("list_preference_1","");
        b=sharedPreferences1.getString("list_preference_2","");

        //a=sharedPreferences1.getInt("list_preference_1", 1);
        //b=sharedPreferences1.getInt("list_preference_2", 1);


        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();

        try {
            //JSONObject ob=json.getJSONObject("settings");
            json.put("notification",Integer.parseInt(a));
            json.put("time",Integer.parseInt(b));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        JSONObject jsonfinal=new JSONObject();

        try {
            jsonfinal.put("settings",json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest1=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlset, jsonfinal, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Changes made to server", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Check internet connectivity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        requestQueue1.add(jsonObjectRequest1);

    }
```

But now my application is now crashing. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: You can `POST`as `JSONObject json=new JSONObject(); json.put("notification","value") and json.put("time","value")` where value is the String etc you want to POST.

Comment: Create another JSONObject as `JSONObject final = new JSONObject();` and put that `json` object as `final.put("settings",json)` and pass final JSONObject in Volley `POST` request.

Comment: Kindly take a look at my edited version @Satyam